# How to associate a column in a table with a specific user

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a social website for delivering objects.
I'm trying to assign a location to a user. If the user adds location the location is added to the user only and saved in DB so that the next time he comes to add a product he can select the location he has already added.

The problem that I can not assign a location to a specific user is added to DB and appears to all users.

The models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,  related_name="pro", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='img/profile/')
    phone = models.CharField("Phone Number", max_length=10 , blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=cy.city, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    home_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city +" "+self.city+" "+ self.street+" "+ self.home_number

class Add_Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories  = models.CharField(max_length=255 , choices= all_categories)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=cond)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='img/')
    more_imges = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='img/')
    Pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,  related_name="loc", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title +" "+self.condition
```

View:

```
class AddLocationView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = AddLocationForm
    template_name ='add_location.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("add-item")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.location = self.request.user_id
        return super().form_valid(form)

class AddItemView(CreateView):
    model = Add_Item
    form_class = AddItemForm
    template_name ='add_item.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you have the line `form.instance.location = self.request.user_id`.
This line does not do anything; here `form.instance` is a `Location` instance, but that instance does not have a field named `location`, so the value is just discarded and NOT saved with the instance.

---

If you want to show to the user only the locations that he added, then you could add a field to the model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    ...
```

and change your view so that it saves the current user (`self.request.user`) with the new location:

```
class AddLocationView(CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.added_by = self.request.user
        self.object.save()

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And finally you could modify your `AddItemForm` (the code of this form is not in the question) to filter the options by the current request user.